# fetch href attribute value using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to loop over a table using nokogiri and fetch href attribute value.

My code is as shown below:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def company_bod(abbrv)

doc=Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=#{abbrv}"))

data = doc.css('.column1 tbody.dataSmall').first if doc.css('.column1')

data.css('tr').each do |col|
    puts col.xpath('//td/h2/a/@href').text()

    #puts col.css('td[2]').text()
    #puts col.css('td[3]').text()
    #puts col.css('td[4]').text() 

end 

company_bod("GOOGL.O")
```

but this is returning me a set of urls across all the tables present on http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=GOOGL.O, whereas I need it to loop only across the table which is present below summary picking href attribute values.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `col.css('td[1] h2 a').attr("href")` seems to do the trick for me. I am sure there is more than one way to accomplish this.

Comment: Try this `col.xpath('//td/h2/a/@href').first.value`

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". You need to reduce your HTML down to the bare minimum that demonstrates the problem and put it into your question. Links, both in code, or in the question itself, tend to rot then break, and when they do the question will make no sense. Also, asking us to retrieve an entire page and sift through it wastes our time, delaying our answers, so by you doing the filtering up front you help us to help you and give us more time to help others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor the xpath queries on the elements

- `node.xpath("//example")` does a global search
- `node.xpath(".//example")` does a local search starting at the current node

Notice the leading dot `.` which anchors the query at the current node. Otherwise the query is run against the root node, even if you call it from the current node.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you